# Why does scrapy pipeline require something to be returned?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

According to the [document](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#process_item), it says we need to return either `dict` or `item` or raise `DropItem` exception. I understand that this might be used if a user uses JSON exporter, but if I built a MongoDB pipeline that doesn't use scrapy exporter, what's the purpose of returning an item? It seems like scrapy outputs whatever is returned to the screen, and it really clutters the screen up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to return any `dict` or `item` if you build a MongoDB pipeline. A simple code for a mongo pipeline would be something like this:

```
class MongoPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        #some code for mongo client connection

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.col.insert(dict(item))
```

Comment: I ran it after commenting out `return item`, yet it doesn't seem to be a problem. I was just confused with the strong wording "must either return ... or raise..." and was wondering if there was a catch I didn't know about.

Comment: The only difference I think would be that the response will not be printed on the screen if you remove the `return item` statement and you might see an empty dict on the screen.

Comment: Yep, it returns `None`, and runs a lot faster. If remove ``return item` doesn't affect the program, I am thinking of returning only ids instead of entire dict